# How can i access my webpage with a subfolder path with nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

This is my Nginx config

```
 server {
  server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

  index index.html index.htm;

location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  proxy_set_header Host                 $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto    "https";
  }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

When I type subdomain.mydomain.com everything works as expected and i can see grafana (which is hosted on that server)

What I want is to type in subdomain.mydomain.com/mysite and access the website, that is hosted in /var/www/html

What do I need to alter in my config to archive that?

Thanks

Comment: Add: `location /mysite { alias /var/www/html; }` - ensure that **both** the `location` and `alias` values end with a `/` - or neither ends with a `/` - see [the `alias` documentation here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

Comment: Hmm done, i've added it before the first location entry, but i always end up on the same page (grafana) no matter, what subfolder i choose